# how to link keywords separated by comma to search value

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, keyword

I have a table of books with column of keywords. keywords are stored separated by comma like social,fiction,art etc., I want to link them as search value when any one click one of them key word related  books be shown in search.ph. My search Query is as under:

```
<?php
include("admin/config.php");
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search_id=$_REQUEST['value'];
$rs=mysql_query("SELECT * from novels where keywords like '%$search_id%' order by 1 limit 0,16");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli` and `PDO` comments in 3 2 1...

Comment: SQL injection comments in 3, 2, 1... also. Don't forget to protect you query from `$_GET` variable by adding slashes and everything else...